# Error while compiling app

Tags: android, dependencies, classpath, android-gradle-plugin, pid

> Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'Myapp'.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Timeout waiting to lock artifact cache (C:\Users\prasid444.gradle\caches\modules-2). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
>        Owner PID: 5232
>        Our PID: 7292
>        Owner Operation: resolve configuration ':classpath'
>        Our operation: resolve configuration ':classpath'
>        Lock file: C:\Users\prasid444.gradle\caches\modules-2\modules-2.lock

Answer (score 3):

Gradle will sometimes leave a gradle-daemon running that can hold locks on your project files. The directory indicated `C:\Users\prasid444.gradle\caches\modules-2` is a cache directory for temporary files.

You can move/remove the folder and try the build again. (Move it to a temporary location in case you have cached files that may be hard to obtain, which should not happen, or you simply want piece of mind while fixing this problem.)

Also, there may be references to files in a `.lock` file somewhere. You can try a `gradle clean build` command or just move/remove everything in `C:\Users\prasid444.gradle\caches`

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything in `~/.gradle/caches` directory and `restart/rebuild` the project.